# Different user types with different data

Tags: php, mysql, propel

I've got a project, to build a model agency cms.
The back end and other parts are okay for me, what I am inexperienced with is the different users, and I am stuck with the logic.

My logic would be this

Create a groups table with the following names and levels

```
id |    group_id     | level
1  |    Admin        | 20
2  |    Moderator    | 10
3  |    Model        | 1
4  |    Photographer | 1
5  |    Stylist      | 1
6  |    Agency       | 1
```

the group id and user id would be saved in an users groups table like this

```
group_id | user_id
1        |       1
1        |       5
1        |       6
3        |       10
```

And here comes what I am stuck with it, so since these users have different data, I was thinking to create multiple forms for them with some fields hidden what is not needed for the actual user type, and when someone browses the profile, a switch chase would be made for the group check, and show different profiles

example

```
switch ($user->groupId) {
    case 3:
        // model profile
        break;

    case 4:
        // photographer profile
        break;

    // and others
}
```

Is it a good logic in a way? Could somebody show me some examples or give me a hint?

Thank you

**Edit**

I am not using framework, i have made my own basic cms based on [propel](http://propelorm.org/)

Comment: Are you using a framework or programming in pure PHP?

Comment: With the logic you have laid out, your group-to-user table would/should allow for many-to-many.  If each user can only be a part of one group, that should be part of the user's table as it would take less space and be easier to get/modify.  If each user can be a part of multiple groups, the tables are set up nicely for it, but you would have to check for the highest priority group for the display aspect.

Comment: thank you for the reply @jon i think i will do some more research, but your aswer helped me a bit

Comment: To keep things simple, I would save the `group_id` as a column in the `user` table. You already have a simple fine tuning with the `level` attribute (even though I would drop that for the sake of simplicity).

IF in the future you need more fine-grained privileges you could THEN treat the `group_id` attribute as the main group and add additional `group` and `group_x_user` tables to implement that. This would enable multiple groups per user, if ever necessary.

Answer (score 0):

IMO the best way to achieve this is to try using Single Table Inheritance or Concrete Table Inheritance in Propel. You can read about it here http://propelorm.org/Propel/documentation/09-inheritance.html